# Como separar bibliotecas em uma suíte de aplicativos?

Tags: java, arquitetura-de-software, framework

Tenho uma suíte de aplicativos web composta de diversas aplicações, cada uma especializada em uma área da empresa, tais como gestão de propriedades, gestão de contratos, gestão de RH, gestão de obras, entre outras. Todos os módulos acessam a mesma base de dados, porém são aplicações separadas.

Em algum momento, esses módulos utilizam classes e entidades em comum, por exemplo, a classe responsável pelas propriedades é utilizada na gestão de obras e na gestão de contratos, além da própria gestão de propriedades. Há inúmeras situações semelhantes. Para resolver esse problema, criamos uma biblioteca gigante contendo todas as classes de negócio e persistência que possam ser utilizadas por dois ou mais módulos.

Com isso criamos outro problema, pois um módulo menor acaba importando uma biblioteca gigantesca apenas para utilizar duas ou três classes.

Que tipo de arquitetura costumeiramente é utilizada para comportar esse tipo de situação que, acredito, seja comum? Criar várias pequenas bibliotecas? EJB é uma saída para esse tipo de problema?

Uso java 7, struts 1.x, hibernate 3 e tomcat 7.

Answer (score 4):

Para cada grupo de entidades fortemente relacionado, crie um pacote. Por exemplo, haverá um pacote com as entidades de propriedades. Haverá outro pacote com as entidades do RH. Não existe, por si só, problema em um pacote depender de vários outros que dependem de vários outros, o que ocorre é que isso pode atrair outros problemas. Os principais problemas são:

- O pacote A depende do pacote B que por sua vez depende do pacote A. Dependências cíclicas são coisas horríveis que ninguém merece. A existência de uma dependência cíclica pode indicar que os pacotes A e B deveriam ser um só ou então que há alguma coisa errada na sua arquitutura. Nunca aceite ter uma dependência cíclica e sempre tente eliminá-las o quanto antes.
- O pacote A depende do pacote B que depende do pacote C, mas o pacote C é um peso morto e inútil para A. Neste caso isso significa que o pacote B está inchado, e possivelmente seja o caso de dividi-lo em pacotes menores.

O que você tem que ter em mente são as regras de encapsulamento, baixo acoplamento e alta coesão, que são mais ou menos as mesmas que se aplicam com classes.

Prefira utilizar uma arquitetura de recursos (REST) ou serviços (SOA) se possível. Por exemplo, no banco de dados do RH, quem mexe deveria ser apenas o RH, pois este é o sistema que concentra o conhecimento de negócio do RH e o seu banco de dados é parte deste conhecimento. Assim, os demais sistemas que precisem de alguma informação advinda do RH deveriam invocar o serviço do RH para fazer as suas tarefas, e nunca acessar o banco de dados diretamente. Observe que isso daqui nada mais é do que o conceito de encapsulamento aplicado em um nível mais alto. Acessar o banco de dados de um outro sistema é uma forma de violar o encapsulamento deste outro sistema. E um dos benefícios do encapsulamento é o controle do acesso (e da sanidade e da manutenibilidade) dos dados privados. Neste ponto, o seu serviço também será o equivalente a uma interface. Se você garantir que cada aplicação mexa apenas no seu banco de dados, poderá evitar de que alterações que forem necessárias ao longo do tempo no banco de dados de um sistema causem efeitos colaterais em outros sistemas.

Uma forma de buscar reduzir o acoplamento é por interfaces que separem a especificação da implementação. Isso, aliado com a arquitetura de serviços ou recursos, permite você reduzir drasticamente as suas dependências. Ao invés de depender de um caminhão de classes que alteram o banco de dados de outro sistema, você passa a depender apenas de uma interface para este outro sistema e de uma implementação do tipo *stub* deste sistema. *Stubs* nada mais são do que implementações destas interfaces que fazem as respectivas chamadas remotas. Se você preferir usar o EJB (não é necesssário, mas é uma alternativa), provavelmente neste caso você não vai precisar criar os *stubs*, pois o EJB já cuida disso. Uma outra alternativa simples é o RMI, mas eu recomendaria usar JSON com Servlets ou JAX-RS.

Uma forma de aumentar a coesão, é garantir que os seus pacotes não são nem muito grandes, com funcionalidades que não deveriam pertencer a eles e nem muito pequenos, com funcionalidades faltando ou delegadas aos clientes. Se forem grandes demais (pode ser boa ideia dividí-los em pacotes menores). Se forem pequenos demais (ou para usar um termo mais preciso, anêmicos), então pode ser que você tenha separado coisas que não deviam ser separadas.

Comment: Muito boa resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Já trabalhei em um ambiente parecido com esse, isto é, cada sistema da suíte precisa incluir outros N sistemas para usar suas classes e entidades.

Hoje encaro isso como um problema, um erro arquitetural, uma falha de projeto.

Um determinado sistema não deveria incluir partes de outros sistemas que não se constituem rotinas genéricas ou gerais aos sistemas. Exagerando um pouco, seria como querer incluir o algoritmo do Google dentro do meu blog para fazer pesquisas em minhas postagens.

Um dos maiores problemas que isso gera é que logo você terá várias versões dos sistemas executando em diferentes aplicações. Cada correção em um determinado sistema vai gerar atualizações em vários outros sistemas. Alguém pode até pensar em alguma política de atualização que funcione na teoria, mas a prática logo vai ensinar que isso não é nada fácil.

Como o Vitor Stafusa já disse na outra resposta, o ideal é que cada sistema utilize dos serviços providos pelos outros sistemas dos quais dependa. Em outras palavras, cada sistema disponibilizado em sua própria instância no servidor de aplicação acessando uns aos outros via uma API REST.